# SQL multiple selecting from two tables and group

Tags: mysql, sql

i have problem with select.

I managed to write a query that was doing something similar but I was able to pull data after only one I need to group as a team but with two names

I have a problem to write one question, I need to pick something about this style

```
team_id | player1       | player2       | position  | category
1       | John Newman   | Andy Roddick  | 1         | 1
2       | Roger Federer | Rafael Nadal  | 1         | 1
```

I have two tables/ one contains players and second contains attendance in team/

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `atendance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `datum_n` date NOT NULL,
  `klub` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `cas` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `foto` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `pass` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `valid_from` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `valid_until` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `is_admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pohlavie` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;
```

Comment: what query you tried?

Comment: where is sample data , desirec output . and whatyouhavetried?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what do you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `JOIN` particularly `LEFT JOIN`, like:

```
SELECT t.id, p1.name, p2.name, t.position, t.category
FROM atendance t
LEFT JOIN players p1
ON t.player1 = p1.id
LEFT JOIN players p2
ON t.player2 = p2.id
```

Comment: I don't really understand you but good that it works for you because you already accepted my answer. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Comment: sry this is right answer : Thank you this is exactly what I needed I made ​​a mistake at that point that I used the second LEFT JOIN OR .. like this
LEFT JOIN players p1
ON t.player1 = p1.id
OR JOIN players p2
ON t.player2 = p2.id

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As much as i understood, all the required data is in first table. You just need to fire,

```
SELECT ID, PLAYER1, PLAYER2, POSITION, CATEGORY FROM ATENDANCE
```

Please note, instead of `CREATE` commands provide the output result of that table, as you want `SELECT` statement to be built. It makes easier to understand.